# Any UI log monitoring tool for cassandra system.log?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, scylla

I am just looking any UI based tool to monitor cassandra system.log so that we could analyze and extract errors efficiently. if any please let me know the steps to configure.

Answer (score 2):

As usual people use ELK stack - Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana, where Kibana is a UI

Comment: Yes but we can install ELK. Any other tool or utlity?